# mingw-w64 searches for libws2_32.dll instead of ws2_32.dll

Tags: c, windows, dll, mingw-w64

With mingw-w64 version 4.9.1, installed with the MSYS2 installer, I'm building a DLL and linking it to `ws2_32.dll` using the `-lws2_32` option. But mingw-w64 can't find `ws2_32.dll` under that name:

```
*** Warning: linker path does not have real file for library -lws2_32.
```

If I go into `C:\Windows\system32` and *copy* `ws2_32.dll` to `libws2_32.dll`, then mingw-w64 can find it. This seems like a bad hack, however. I tried `-l:ws2_32` since I read that the ":" has special meaning, but that made no difference.

**How can I tell mingw-w64 to link to a Windows DLL whose name does not begin with lib?**

Comment: It's been a while, so this might not work, but try linking with `-lws2_32.dll`.

Comment: In addition, also try specifying the name of the .dll on the command line _without_ `-l`.

Comment: You should be able to use `-l:ws2_32.dll`.  With the colon, you must specify the complete file name, including extension, but the linker still searches the library path for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried fore-going the `-l` option?

Just

```
gcc -LC:\Windows\system32 herpmytargetcodederp.c ws2_32.dll
```

Items fed into gcc are either object files or libraries.  The `-l` option is just a common way of linking in commonly used things a little easier. The old farts were terse.  `-lm` instead of typing out `-L/path/to/lib libmath.o`

Include the path for the linker to find it with `-L` and call it by name.

Answer (score 1):

you do not link to the DLL itself, but to the library that defines the dll exports (libws2_32.a), check in your MingW (\lib) directory if `libws2_32.a` exists.